# How do I smooth current dips on a USB charger?

Tags: capacitor, charger

I've got a USB charger that I want to use to charge a phone.  For about 35 seconds it outputs enough current for the phone to detect it and start charging, then for an instant (no equipment to read the length of time, let's call it a quarter second) the current drops to 0, then picks right back up.  This is verified via a small USB flashlight that exhibits the same behavior.

This is a problem because the phone detects it as the plug being removed and reinserted which jolts the screen back on, resulting in a loss of charge.

Is there a relative simple and small footprint way to smooth this out so that I get steady current?  My fuzzy memory of hanging out with EE people in college makes me think the answer is capacitors, but I have no idea how to do this or how large of a capacitor I need.

Comment: Large cap alone MAY suffice. Small chance that charger will not like this. | If so, feed via Schottky diode into large cap and then to phone MAY work if diode drop is not too much for phone. | If diode too much then a FET designed to not back feed plus large cap WILL work. This can be done with probably only  parts (cap, FET). Ask if interested.

Comment: Do the question closers not read the questions they close? | this is entirely about electronic design. The specific question is "Is there a relative simple and small footprint way to smooth this out so that I get steady current? " . How is that conceivably NOT a question about electronic design? How is this not specific enough for an answer? My other comment provides a solution that WILL work and one that may.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be the USB master going into thermal reset due to sustained high current draw. It could as well be resetting due to overcurrent protection, but that generally wouldn't kick in after 35 seconds but much sooner.

***Caveat Emptor***:

If the USB port simply cannot supply as much current as the device requires over a sustained period, neither of the two solutions below will do you the least bit of good. The resets will continue, at best with a longer cycle than 35 seconds, and at worst even faster because the capacitor charging trips overcurrent protection.

**Simple solution**: Hefty capacitor between +5V and GND lines. Start with a 4700 uF 12 Volt electrolytic (*just because those are common enough, and inexpensive*). If that doesn't work well enough, keep adding more.

**More complex solution**: An inductor-capacitor combination: Two hefty inductors, say 100 uH 1 Ampere each (*just because those are common enough, and inexpensive*), on the +5V and the GND lines, followed by a capacitor between them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSl5Zc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The inductors will slow down the inrush current spike when the capacitor is charging up at power on. This prevents the USB port from going into overcurrent protection / reset.

Comment: I'm hoping it's not thermal reset or overcurrent protection.  The problem persists with low draw devices: a flashlight bundled with the charger and a mouse.  The flickers are periodic too, almost exactly every 35 seconds.

Comment: One more data point.  I sat down and timed it.  Flickers happen every 15-25 seconds.

Comment: @Hounshell With that kind of period, it is almost definitely overheating. A detached or missing heat sink within the charger could cause a thermal reset even with low currents - in which case the capacitors or the LC suggested above will not do a thing for you. Just get a new charger, they're cheap and ubiquitous these days.

Comment: Trickle charging and overcurrent protection kicking in?

Comment: It's a fuel cell charger (so, not that cheap).  Contacted the manufacturer.  If no response I'll return it as non-functioning.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - Suggestion only: It's possibly a handshake / negotiation sequence used to pass information between charger and target device. As it's made for a non-phone application it need not necessarily comply with phone standards.

Comment: Return it. You shouldn't have to redesign a commercial electrical product. Re-purposing or fixing an old product, fine. But not straight out of the box. 

Any particular reason you need a fuel cell USB charger?

Comment: @user1512321 If that were me who bought it, I'd say "Geek toy!!!!!" :-)

Comment: @Ghosh Sure, if that was my intention. But if I bought to use it, to rely on it, I'd have to return it. Especially since it was suggested that it is expensive!

Comment: @user1512321 My comment was no reflection on your intentions, just why *I* want one. :-)

Comment: @Ghosh, our intentions are the same. That's why I up voted you :D

Comment: Sorry I disappeared, but it took a little bit to resolve this.  First, the charger is the Horizon fuel cell, around $100. I contacted company, they sent a replacement, same issue. I'm sticking with it because it's the most legit, rechargable fuel cell I've found. This is going to be used on a few long cycling trips. It offers a pretty compelling weight to power ratio without affecting drag. This solution worked with a single 4.7mF cap, but I wired a second in anyway in case it gets slightly worse over time. So far it's charged a cell phone fully without an issue, so I'd call it a success.